# How can I decorate form input elements with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Looking for a quick way to add classes needed to my input elements using jQuery. I believe I need to add the following classes but I am not sure how to add these and also if I need to add the hover classes.

```
ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all
```

Does anyone have suggestions on what to add and how to add the classes including hover? I checked the documentation but I can't see even one small mention of this on the jQuery site :-(

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating widgets and want to use jQuery UI themes in them, the The [jQuery UI CSS Framework](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming/API) page tells you what the CSS classes and such are used for.

In terms of adding the `-hover` and `-active` classes, there's jQuery's [`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover) function for the former, and the [`focus`](http://api.jquery.com/focus) and [`blur`](http://api.jquery.com/blur) events for the latter. You add and remove classes via [`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass) and [`removeClass`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass).

---

**Update**: Below you say you're not creating a widget, you're just trying to apply something to a simple text box. As far as I'm aware, there's nothing for you to do, no classes for you to add. Look at the [theme roller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/), for instance: The input box for the autocompleter has no classes on it except those added by the *autocompleter* code. You don't add them, you set up the autocompleter on the element and *it* adds them. As far as I'm aware, that's the case throughout: You set up widgets by calling their plug-in functions at runtime, and if necessary, the *widget* code will add any classes it needs to the elements.

If you're just trying to style other elements on the page so they fit in well with the theme — even without creating a widget — the page linked above should tell you what you need to know to do that. But by and large, you mostly don't. jQuery UI isn't a website CSS framework; the CSS is targeted to the specific things jQuery UI provides (but in a nice holistic way so the whole thing can be themed in a uniform way).

Comment: I'm not creating a widget. Just want something to apply to a simple text input box. I know for the experts this is probably easy but I am surprised that there is no advice given to everyone else. After all I guess 100% of people use an input box on their sites and there's no mention of how to theme it. Any idea why it's not even mentioned on the site?

Comment: @SamanthaJ: I've updated the answer. You don't theme input boxes with jQuery UI as far as I know. That would be why there's no mention of it on the site.

Comment: I thought there was a long term plan to add form decorator controls to jQuery UI? I see mention of it but it seems like something that never gets finished.

Comment: @SamanthaJ: See [the roadmap](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138038/Roadmap). Form controls are listed as a 2.0 feature. They're working on 1.9 at the moment, and there will be at least a 1.10 prior to 2.0.